# exact match using RAW field not working in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am trying to query for all documents where

`Message.raw: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

The query execute successfully but documents returned contain documents where message does NOT equal 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'.  I feel like it is doing a match for any message with any word within my text.  i.e. it is finding message where the word 'not' is within that message.

In the ElasticSearch index I have specified this field to be 'not_analyzed'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try double quotes instead of single quotes

Comment: Wow...  That was it...  Thank you so much for that.  Do you know why double quotes and single quotes make a difference?  Does it just drive how Kibana structures the query?

Comment: The double quotes are mandated by the [query string query syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_field_names), which Kibana uses. Single quotes mean nothing and are just discarded.